# Set text with two different colors in edit control

Tags: mfc

How to write text in a same edit control or rich edit control with two different color??

Answer (score 0):

You can use richedit control. The tutorial is there: http://win32assembly.online.fr/tut33.html found at http://www.win32developer.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=212